# Unable to shrink new xubuntu LVM partition

Tags: xubuntu, gparted, lvm

I just installed xubuntu onto a new drive and I want to make sure that I can shrink it before I start using it. I tried to shrink it while booted into the live cd, but could do it in GParted *or* gnome-disks.

Edit: I installed "Logical Volume Management" which doesn't seem to let me shrink the partitions. I also installed "KVPM" which advertises LVM support, but will also only let me reduce the partition by 32 mb.

Comment: To make changes to an LVM partition, you must use LVM tools. GParted and gnome-disks are not LVM tools.

Comment: @user535733 I installed "Logical Volume Management" which doesn't seem to let me shrink the partitions. I also installed "KVPM" which advertises LVM support, but will also only let me reduce the partition by 32 mb. Any advice on what program to use?